# Show $U^TQQ^TU$ = $Q^TUU^TQ$ $= I$, if $X=UDV^T$ is the skinny SVD of X and $X=QR$ is its skinny QRD

Tags: self-study, matrix-decomposition

I have that $X$ is a full rank $n$ by $p$ matrix with $n>p$. Let $X=UDV^T$ denote the skinny SVD of $X$ and let $X = QR$ denote its skinny QRD (skinny is also sometimes referred to as economic).

I need to show $U^TQQ^TU = Q^TUU^TQ = I$.

To do this, do I need to equate $QR = UDV^T$? If so, whats the relationship between these two decompositions where I could proceed to show the required?

Answer (score 1):

For any matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, we can decompose it via SVD
$$X=USV^T \text{ , } U^TU=UU^T=I_n$$
or QR
$$X=QR \text{ , } Q^TQ=QQ^T=I_n$$
where $U,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), and $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

For a "tall" matrix with $n>p$, these decompositions are over-complete, so we have corresponding "skinny" [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Reduced_SVDs) and [QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix) decompositions
$$X=U_0S_0V^T=Q_0R_0$$
where now $U_0,Q_0\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ are *rectangular* matrices with $U_0^TU_0^\phantom{T}=Q_0^TQ_0^\phantom{T}=I_p$ but
$U_0^\phantom{T}U_0^T\neq I_n$ and $Q_0^\phantom{T}Q_0^T\neq I_n$.

For the "full" case ($U$ and $Q$), the requested proof would be trivial. For the "thin" case, consider what the difference is.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I forgot that edits can be viewed! I deleted the old answer and put this as a new one.